# How do I force parent component re render from child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS.
I have a component, named `A`, and this component is correspondings to path: `.../a`
Inside `A`, I have component `B`, and inside `B`, I have component `C`, and so on...
How do I force component `A` to be re-rendered from component `Z` ?
I've searched for an hour, the are some possible solutions such as: `setState`, passing `re-render` function. But i think it's not good for the distance A-Z.
I also tried `history.push(".../a")` but seems like it don't work with the current path.

Comment: Why does component A need to re-render? Giving more context around what you are trying to accomplish might prompt better help.

Comment: In my app, the component A is MyPlaylist, and component Z is a submit button, which inside the many parent component: AddPlaylistButton, AddPlaylistPopup,... When submit, I need the MyPlaylist component to re-render and update new created playlist from above submit.

Comment: That makes it much clearer. I would create a Context to wrap your Playlist state and functions for updating that state. Expose those to your components lower in the tree and the state will update in all of them.

Comment: I left an answer with what that could look like and a simple explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of what a Context that wrapped a Playlist object *could* look like.

Here we have 2 components, `PlaylistDetails` and `AddSongForm`, and a single Context, `PlaylistContext`. Our `PlaylistProvider` *wraps* the `PlaylistContext` and exposes both the playlist state (the list of songs) and a function to update that state. The `PlaylistDetails` and `AddSongForm` components read the `playlist` state from the `PlaylistProvider` so whenever that is updated they re-render automatically.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const PlaylistContext = createContext(null);

const PlaylistProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [playlist, setPlaylist] = useState([]);

  const updatePlaylist = (songName) => {
    setPlaylist((prevPlaylist) => [...prevPlaylist, songName]);
  };

  return (
    <PlaylistContext.Provider value={{ playlist, updatePlaylist }}>
      {children}
    </PlaylistContext.Provider>
  );
};

const PlaylistDetails = () => {
  const { playlist } = useContext(PlaylistContext);

  if (playlist.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Songs:</h1>
      <ul>
        {playlist.map((song) => (
          <li key={song}>{song}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

const AddSongForm = () => {
  const { updatePlaylist } = useContext(PlaylistContext);
  const [songName, setSongName] = useState(null);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        updatePlaylist(songName);
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <label>
        Song Name:
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setSongName(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Add Song</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <PlaylistProvider>
      <PlaylistDetails />

      <AddSongForm />
    </PlaylistProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "useContext" hook to achieve the solution for above problem.

“useContext” hook is used to create common data that can be accessed throughout the component hierarchy without passing the props down manually to each level. Context defined will be available to all the child components without involving “props”.

A simple example for your understanding. I recommend you to go through this example. You can find details about implementation here

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const UserContext = createContext();

function Component1() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("Jesse Hall");

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
      <h1>{`Hello ${user}!`}</h1>
      <Component2 user={user} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Component2() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 2</h1>
      <Component3 />
    </>
  );
}

function Component3() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 3</h1>
      <Component4 />
    </>
  );
}

function Component4() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 4</h1>
      <Component5 />
    </>
  );
}

function Component5() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 5</h1>
      <h2>{`Hello ${user} again!`}</h2>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component1 />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent component needs to have a state update in order to re-render. I  would keep that state in a reusable hook so it's accessible to any child but I strongly advice you rethink your component structure.

e.g.

```
function useSongs() {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);

  return { songs, setSongs };
}

function Playlist() {
  const { songs } = useSongs();

  // do whatever you want with the songs here

  return <AvailableSongs />;
}

function AvailableSongs() {
  // imagine having a list here, for demo I'll return one song
  return <Song title="Adele - Easy on me" />;
}

function Song({ title }) {
  const { songs, setSongs } = useSongs();

  const handleClick = (title) => () => {
    setSongs([...songs, title]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {title}
      <button onClick={handleClick(title)}>
        Add to playlist
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```